# How do I work with TypeScript correctly when I need to change a type of a property in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have this class that represents JSON incoming from POST request.

```ts
class MilkCarton {
  company: string;
  price: number;
  expiredAt?: string;
  // ...20 more properties
}
```

Before I store it in my mongoDB database, I want to change the type of `expiredAt` to `Date`, so I have another class that represents the schema of the database.

```ts
class MilkCartonSchema: {
  company: string;
  price: number;
  expiredAt?: Date;
  // ...20 more properties
}
```

`expiredAt` can be null, I want to create an object that copies the object of type `MilkCarton` but has its `expiredAt` converted to `Date`

```ts
prepareMilkForDb(milk: MilkCarton): MilkCartonSchema {
  const preparedMilk = {
    ...milk,
  }

  if (milk.expiredAt) {
    preparedMilk.expiredAt = new Date(milk.expiredAt)
  }

  return preparedMilk;
}
```

But I run into an error because `preparedMilk` has already inferred its type and has `expiredAt` as `string`, it can't be turned into `Date` from TypeScript perspective if it's `string`. But I want it to turn into `Date`, what is the approach to do that correctly in TypeScript?

**EDIT:**
I ended up going with:

```ts
prepareMilkForDb(milk: MilkCarton): MilkCartonSchema {
  const preparedMilk = {
    ...milk,
    ...(milk.expiredAt && {
      expiredAt: new Date(milk.expiredAt)
    }),
  }

  return preparedMilk;
}
```

This works, but isn't exactly what I wished for, if I had another example with 3 different deep nested ISO `string` properties that need converting to `Date` (and backwards) it would be very dirty to do this workaround.

Comment: Something like `return { ...milk, expiredAt: new Date(milk.expiredAt) }`, but note the string is optional hit the date is required - what date do you put for an undefined input?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I fixed it `date` should be optional too.

The problem with what you suggest is I think `new Date(milk.expiredAt)` will throw an error if `milk.expiredAt` is `undefined`. (and if instead it returns `undefined` it's still not something I want because I don't want to store `undefined` in my database and I'm not sure I even can in mongoDB anymore)

Comment: So start from `const { expiredAt, ...preparedMilk } = milk`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
Thanks it does solve it in a way, if I understand correctly, after what you suggest I would do

`if (milk.expiredAt) preparedMilk['expiredAt']  = milk.expiredAt`

Because I can't do `preparedMilk.expiredAt = milk.expiredAt`  since after the destruct ring `preparedMilk` doesn't have property `expiredAt`.

Still feels kinda "hacky" I was hoping there was a nicer typescript solution that doesn't try to bypass it, but still thanks nonetheless it does solve me the problem for now I can't think of anything cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
interface MilkCarton {
    company: string;
    price: number;
    expiredAt?: string;
    // ...20 more properties
}

interface MilkCartonSchema {
    company: string;
    price: number;
    expiredAt?: Date;
    // ...20 more properties
}

const prepareMilkForDb = (milk: MilkCarton): MilkCartonSchema => {
    return {
        ...milk,
        expiredAt: milk.expiredAt == null ? undefined : new Date(milk.expiredAt)
    };
}
```

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLLADYGsDCcpgD2IyA3gFDJXIKEC2ADnCAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYBuStQa8kHEAFc6AI2hDqyCAA8GwKBAAmAQTAB+Dt14hBwqgHpzyAHS2ATAAZkdQhuSjCDaGGARO5AF9yclBIWEQUdGw8AmIAZQQACwg6ODIzGnomVkMefgURMQgJaTkoAqoVNQ0dfQ4AEThICuRLG3snFzcPLwJffyDyWhBudw0mDSisADFXeplkAF5kAAo6TCwOKZiiEABKLY2d+KSUtMWAPnTFDTBJKBIKRUVba3XsABoMxSr1LV0OO8sNZfjVdEtllIMBhkHpkJIQJoIDBQFpkBIIAB3ZCNSBrDYg1R-Wp7DIBIQBIA)

*Note: I changed the classes to interface, I don't know if that's ok or not?*

Comment: Thanks for answering, it almost works but I don't want `expiredAt` to be null and inserted into the database as a null value, I would like to not insert it at all if it's not given to me in the request.

I ended up going with something similar with what you suggested with 
`expiredAt: ...(milk.expiredAt && { expiredAt: new Date(milk.expiredAt) })` then if milk.expiredAt is undefined, it will not add it to the object at all.

Unfortunately this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, it's more of a band-aid, I have another object that has many deep nested date properties, it will be too ugly.

Comment: @user3575645 Can't you use your original function (from your question then) and simply add a type preparedMilk? Meaning: `const preparedMilk: MilkCartonSchema = { ...milk };` (leave the rest of the function as it is).

Comment: That won't work if I understood you correctly, the code line you suggested will raise an error saying I'm trying to assign `string` (`milk.expiredAt`) to `Date` (`MilkCartonSchema` excepts `expiredAt` to be `Date`).

Comment: @user3575645 You're 100% correct, don't mind me 

Comment: @user3575645 one last try! You could add `if (result.expiredAt == null) delete result.expiredAt;` to remove it from the object. This could even be a utility function, since you mentionned needing it in other places too.